# how to get a 2D map using octomap

Tags: navigation, mapping, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and electric ROS.

I've already got 3D map using rgbdslam pkg and now I want to downproject the 3D map to 2D in order for localization. However I cannot find a tutorial on how to do this using octomap though I know it has such a function. Can someone give me any advice? Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36743/how-to-get-a-2d-map-using-octomap/) by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chithra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4141/chithra/) on 2013-02-07**:
Hello, I am currently facing the same problem! How did you solve it? Sorry about opening a closed thread. i am unable to get much info on this online. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[octomap_server](http://ros.org/wiki/octomap_server#Published_Topics) publishes a 2D map on the topic `/map`.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on 2012-06-18**:
I am new in ROS, so I am confused at how to get this 2D map from the topic and use this map for later use. Can you give me some more specific instructions? Thanks a lot !

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2012-06-18**:
try this command
rosrun map_server map_saver -f map , this command will save the map in your current directory

**Comment by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on 2012-06-18**:
do I have to run some command before that?